# Segfault in minimal example of scoped_allocator_adaptor used with vector of unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, std, allocator

I have recently learned about custom allocators in C++11 and am trying to use them in my application. However I am running into a segfault, which can be reproduced by the following minimal example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <scoped_allocator>

template<class T> struct custom_allocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    custom_allocator() noexcept {}
    template <class U> custom_allocator (const custom_allocator<U>&) noexcept {}
    T* allocate (std::size_t n) { return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(n*sizeof(T))); }
    void deallocate (T* p, std::size_t n) { ::delete(p); }
    template <typename U> constexpr bool operator==(const custom_allocator<U>&) const { return true; }
    template <typename U> constexpr bool operator!=(const custom_allocator<U>&) const { return false; }
};

template<class T> using custom_scoped_allocator = std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<custom_allocator<T> >;

typedef std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>,
                           custom_scoped_allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > MyMap;

typedef std::vector<MyMap, custom_scoped_allocator<MyMap> > MyVector;

int main() {
    MyVector vec(1);
    vec[0][0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

The custom allocator is exactly the one suggested in the example at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator_traits/
It is then combined with `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` as I have seen suggested in a few places on the internet.

The code compiles fine with gcc 5.4.0 using `g++ -g3 -O0 -std=c++11 -march=core-avx-i -o tmpalloc tmpalloc.cpp`. When I attempt to run it, a segfault is reported starting with

```
*** Error in `./tmpalloc': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ae3c90 ***
```

If I recompile using AddressSanitizer, I get the following details about the double free: https://pastebin.com/raw/xy2NQtD0
(Sorry for the pastebin but it is not pretty.)
Basically, the destructor for an unordered_map object seems to be called twice.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `allocate` function allocates a bunch of bytes, but does not call any constructors (by directly invoking the `operator new` global function).  Your `deallocate` function invokes `delete` on a typed pointer, which results in the destructor for that type being called before the global `operator delete` function is called to free the memory.  The end result is that you destruct memory that you did not construct (the construction and destruction are handled by the caller after/before your `allocate`/`deallocate` functions are called.

You should be releasing the memory using a complementary method to the way you allocate it.  In C++14 or later, this would be:

```
void deallocate (T* p, std::size_t n) { ::operator delete(p, n * sizeof(T)); }
```

where `n` is value passed to `allocate`, and the second parameter is the value passed to `new`.  Prior to C++14, just relay to the single parameter version (which is what the default two parameter operator delete will do):

```
void deallocate (T* p, std::size_t n) { ::operator delete(p); }
```

Comment: I feel you are right but there are some minor caveats:
1) I believe that should read `::operator delete(p, n*sizeof(T));`?                                                                                                                                                                           
2) The corresponding operator overload seems to be available only since C++14. I am actually forced to use C++11. What would be the equivalent there?
3) Is the cplusplus.com example I linked above "correct"? Why doesn't it produce any violation (according to AddressSanitizer)?

Comment: @amakh See my edits.  The example is flawed.  It works in that case because they're using it with `int`, which does nothing when destroyed.

Comment: Great, thanks! AddressSanitizer does report an issue with `::operator delete(p, n)` though: `object passed to delete has wrong type:
  size of the allocated type:   16 bytes;
  size of the deallocated type: 1 bytes.` Using `n*sizeof(T)` fixes that.

Comment: @amakh I've edited again.  I hadn't completely thought thru what I looking at.